# R Programming Stem and Leaf Plot

Tags: r

I have a data set in which I have to make a Stem and Leaf Plot. It consist of number that are in the thousands. The plot has have Stems of thousands and Leafs of hundreds. For some reason it is not working correctly. Can anyone offer any tips here is the data set and code:

```
problem20 = c(1280, 5320, 4390, 2100, 1240, 3060, 4770,
              1050, 360, 3330, 3380, 340, 1000, 960,
              1320, 530, 3350, 540, 3870, 1250, 2400,
              960, 1120, 2120, 450, 2250, 2320, 2400,
              3150, 5700, 5220, 500, 1850, 2460, 5850,
              2700, 2730, 1670, 100, 5770, 3150, 1890,
              510, 240, 396, 1419, 2109)

stem(problem20)
```

Here is my output:

```
The decimal point is 3 digit(s) to the right of the |

0 | 1234455555
1 | 0001123334799
2 | 1113344577
3 | 1223449
4 | 48
5 | 23789`
```

This is the desired output:

```
0|123334555599
1|00122234688
2|1112344477
3|0113338
4|37
5|23778
```

Comment: The is also the `aplpack` package, with `stem.leaf` function that allows different rules

Comment: I think this deserves to be reopened as the op heavily edited amd improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your desired output suggests you want to truncate the data, not round it.  This is probably a bad idea:  after all, 4390 is better summarized as 4400 than as 4300.

But if you really want to do that, use

```
problem20 <- 100 * problem20 %/% 100
stem(problem20)
```

If your instructor or textbook told you that this is the right answer, you should probably take a different course.

Comment: Lol....true. what does <- mean by the way ?